# How to prevent Django Admin Users from changing other Admin Users' profile data?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

I have Admin User extended/subclassed by Teacher class.

How to prevent Teachers from seeing and changing other Teachers' profile data and Teachers are able to change their own records/rows only? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but if what's in your mind is having the built-in user administration pages working slightly differently for Teacher users, then I believe you just have to extend `UserAdmin`, and override the `queryset` method.

```
class TeacherSpecificUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
  def queryset(self, request):
    if request.user.is_teacher():
      return Teacher.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk)
    return UserAdmin.queryset(self, request)
```

That will take care of disallowing Teachers to edit or delete other records, because if you look in the `ModelAdmin` code, `change_view` and `delete_view` method use the queryset returned from `queryset` method to get the object to change or delete.

One more tweak is necessary, because the view used to change the password in `UserAdmin` doesn't use the same system as the others views to get the object to change. Just override it in your new class :

```
...
def user_change_password(self, request, id):
  if request.user.is_teacher() and request.user.pk != int(id):
    # PermissionDenied is in django.core.exceptions
    raise PermissionDenied
  return UserAdmin.user_change_password(self, request, id)
...
```

After that, you just have to prevent Teachers to add new users, or delete their own record. Do that either using the default [django's permission framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/auth/#id1), or by overriding `has_add_permission` and `has_delete_permission` methods.

Have a look in the `ModelAdmin` source code if you want more info (in `contrib/admin/options.py`).

Comment: +1 Thanks Clement! I'm trying to understand the user_change_password(). It's really worth reading the code.

Answer (score 3):

There probably isn't a build in way to do this.

See the [permission docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#id1):

> Permissions are set globally per type of object, not per specific object instance. For example, it's possible to say "Mary may change news stories," but it's not currently possible to say "Mary may change news stories, but only the ones she created herself" or "Mary may only change news stories that have a certain status, publication date or ID." The latter functionality is something Django developers are currently discussing.

However, [object level permissions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2-beta-1/#object-level-permissions) are coming, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this currently, but [object level permissions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2-beta-1/#object-level-permissions) are coming soon in Django 1.2 - although you have to do some work to get it working in the admin.

Luckily there is a [Django Advent article](http://djangoadvent.com/1.2/object-permissions/) which explains what you need to do.